# How can Avast detect threats when I install Kali on VirtualBox?

Tags: malware, linux, antivirus, virtualization, kali-linux

I was installing Kali on VirtualBox on a W7 host, and during the upgrading/installation, Avast detected two threats in the Mimikatz package.

My question is, how can Avast "see" through the VM? Is he package held for a bit on the host, before going in to the VM? I've always thought that the two enviroment were isolated and separated. I downloaded Kali from the official site.

And is it normal that a virus is detected? Is it a false positive?

Answer (score 2):

This is not exclusive to Kali. If you run an apt upgrade for metasploit or mimikaz (from, say, Parrot in a VM), chances are you'll get the same alert from your AV. The reason is that the packet goes through the host machine first (then gets caught by your AV) before being handled by your VM.

> and is normal that be detected as virus? Is false positive?

It's not false positive. It's not a virus either in a sense that it'll cause harm to YOUR machine. Note, *YOUR*. There are exploits and/or scripts in Kali that can legitimately cause harm and is intended to cause harm to identify vulnerabilities in a system.

Answer (score 1):

> I've always thought that 2 enviroment was isolated and separated.

If you are running Kali inside Virtualbox inside Windows then the network traffic from Kali passes through the network stack of Windows - and thus through the traffic analyses from Avast. Since it is still common that the packages are transferred using HTTP and not HTTPS (with the argument that they are signed anyway and thus modifications are detected) Avast can thus detect a download of Mimikatz.

Comment: is possible that kaly had virus inside,form official site?

Comment: @unto _"Avast can thus detect a download of Mimikatz."_ mimikatz is flagged by many antivirus products. It's not something you'd typically find on a regular user system unless it is compromised.

Comment: @multithr3at3d It should be noted that Kali is not a "regular user system" and thus AV warnings should be treated as such

Answer (score 0):

Because the VMs disk is a file inside your MS-Windows disk. Ultimately the content is the same.

Comment: is possible that kaly had virus inside,form official site?

Comment: Mimikatz is a hacking tool, not a virus. Kali is a pen-testing kit. Not all malware is viruses.